# Appendices in Latex and Numbering

Tags: numbering, appendices

I am trying to write a paper with appendices, but the final product comes out numbering all the appendices as A. Can anyone see what is going wrong?

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[draft]{amsart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\appendix \section{Stuff}
\appendix \section{Different Stuff}
\end{document}
```

It comes out as

> Appendix A. Stuff
>
> Appendix A. Different Stuff

Comment: Use `\appendix` just once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `amsart.cls` we find

```
\def\appendix{\par\c@section\z@ \c@subsection\z@
   \let\sectionname\appendixname
   \def\thesection{\@Alph\c@section}}
```

Thus, we can see that the command `\appendix` resets the Section and Subsection counters (with the code `\c@section\z@ \c@subsection\z@`).

Also, it changes the section name to `\appendixname` which is also defined in `amsart.cls` as

```
\def\appendixname{Appendix}
```

Finally, it changes the counter format to Alphabetical (in the code `\@Alph\c@section`).

So, if you use `\appendix` twice the counter will be restored to `A` again.